# Why am I obtaining undefined trying to retrieve an array from this class?

Tags: typescript

I am pretty new in Angular and TypeScript (I came from Java) and I have the following problem.

I have defined this class:

```
export class OrderFormValues {

  public statoOrdine: [
    {label:'Seleziona stato ordine', value:null},
    {label:'Aperto', value:'Aperto'},
    {label:'Chiuso', value:'Chiuso'},
  ]
}
```

that will contains some arrays that I will use to valorize input dropdown in my front end.

Then into my component class I am doing something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

    console.log("orderFormValues VALUES: " + this.orderFormValues.statoOrdine);
    ........................................................
    ........................................................
    ........................................................
}
```

I expected to retrieve the array with its values but I am obtaining this output:

```
orderFormValues VALUES: undefined
```

Why it is undefined? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you instantiate `this.orderFormValues`

Comment: `<access> <name>: <type>` doesn't define a *value*. You're defining an empty class, look at the output in e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4HkoBNhQBi0AtgGopICuwmA3gFANxxhUBGSAlgnGjChgQcuLgDtgALjgBtZizh1U7YEkkByAMqrgALy4QxKPgKFxooieoA0cAG6UaksVSRIAvtfkslKFWvUAQTACIRt7RykgkNgIdU9vRWVVDQBhAAsuKjQ42wdqKIysnPivFgBdBncgA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the assignment of your array is incorrect as you are using : to assign values. When you use the two dots (:) it's meant to declare the type. `myNumber: number = 5`.
So in your case, you'd have to do something like `

```
public statoOrdine: any = [...]
```

Any is not the most correct way to declare the type, but it will work.

Comment: The type seems simple, no need to use `any` - `{ label: string; value: string | null }[]`